# How to properly pass the app object from app.'s to routes.coffee in a Node application

Tags: node.js, express, coffeescript

While following a book example on using Coffeescript with Node.js, I'm trying to define a route in my routes.coffee file as follows:

```
routes = (app) ->


app.get '/login', (req,res) ->

    res.render "views/login",

        title: 'Login'

        stylesheet: 'login'

module.exports = routes
```

The app object is passed (or so it should) to the routes.coffee from the main startup file app.'s:

```
require('./routes')(app);
```

When attempting to start the application (node app) I get the following error:

/Users/eugene/Documents/DevTraining/MeanStack/NodeJS/HotPie/routes.coffee:6

```
  app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  ^
ReferenceError: app is not defined

  at Object.<anonymous> 
(/Users/eugene/Documents/DevTraining/MeanStack/NodeJS/HotPie/routes.coffee:5:1)

  at Object.<anonymous> 

(/Users/eugene/Documents/DevTraining/MeanStack/NodeJS/HotPie/routes.coffee:2:1)

  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)

  at Object.loadFile 

(/Users/eugene/Documents/DevTraining/MeanStack/NodeJS/HotPie/node_modules/coffee-

script/lib/coffee-script/register.js:16:19)

  at Module.load 

(/Users/eugene/Documents/DevTraining/MeanStack/NodeJS/HotPie/node_modules/coffee-

script/lib/coffee-script/register.js:45:36)

  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)

  at Module.require (module.js:364:17)

  at require (module.js:380:17)

  at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/eugene/Documents/DevTraining/MeanStack/NodeJS/HotPie/app.js:34:1)

  at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)

  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)

  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)

  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)

  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)

  at startup (node.js:119:16)

  at node.js:902:3
```

What is the proper way to make this work, please?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it appears, that, after messing around with indentation a little bit, the app object is being recognized:
routes = (app) ->

```
 app.get '/login', (req,res) ->
     res.render "views/login",
        title: 'Login'
        stylesheet: 'login'
```

module.exports = routes